# Force JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<book__entity> to execute a method instead of assigning property value

Tags: c#

I have been stuck for days because of this problem, let me explain, I have the following classes:

In the entity layer:

```
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class telephone__entity
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")] internal int _id;
        [JsonProperty("number")] internal string _number;

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string number { get; set; }
    }

    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class autor__entity
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")] internal int _id;
        [JsonProperty("name")] internal string _name;
        [JsonProperty("telephones")] internal BindingList<telephone__entity> _telephones;

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public BindingList<telephone__entity> telephones { get; set; }

        public autor__entity()
        {
            _telephones = new BindingList<telephone__entity>();

            telephones.ListChanged += telephones_ListChanged;
        }

        private void telephones_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // VALIDATIONS AND CUSTOM OPERATIOS
        }
    }

    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class book__entity
    {
        [JsonProperty("title")] internal string _title;
        [JsonProperty("autors")] internal BindingList<autor__entity> _autors;

        public string titulo { get; set; }
        public BindingList<autor__entity> autors { get; set; }

        public book__entity()
        {
            _autors = new BindingList<autor__entity>();

            autors.ListChanged += autors_ListChanged;
        }

        private void autors_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // VALIDATIONS AND CUSTOM OPERATIOS
        }
    }

    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class library__entity
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")] internal int _id;
        [JsonProperty("books")] internal BindingList<book__entity> _books;

        public int id { get; set; }
        public BindingList<book__entity> books { get; set; }

        public library__entity()
        {
            _books = new BindingList<book__entity>();

            books.ListChanged += books_ListChanged;
        }

        private void books_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // VALIDATIONS AND CUSTOM OPERATIOS
        }
    }
```

In the same layer I have a class that adds the AddRange functionality BindingList type (I will use this functionality in the data layer):

```
public static class BindingListExtensions
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T> bindingList, IEnumerable<T> collection, bool raise_events_enabled = false)
    {
        if (collection != null)
        {
            var oldRaiseEventsValue = bindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents;

            try
            {
                bindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;

                foreach (var value in collection)
                {
                    bindingList.Add(value);
                }
            }

            finally
            {
                bindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = oldRaiseEventsValue;

                if (raise_events_enabled && bindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents)
                {
                    bindingList.ResetBindings();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in the data layer, I have a method that receives a parameter of type IDataReader to then perform the cast accordingly.

```
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var record = new library__entity();
        {
            record._id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
            record._books.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<book__entity>(Convert.ToString(reader["BOOKS"]))); // THIS IS WHERE I HAVE THE ERROR, BECAUSE THE TELEPHONES_LISTCHANGED EVENT OF THE AUTOR__ENTITY CLASS IS BEING FIRED
            
            // 1) CONVERT.TOSTRING(READER["BOOKS"]) GETS A JSON STRING FROM THE DATABASE
            // 2) I AM USING RECORD._BOOKS.ADDRANGE TO PREVENT THE BOOKS_LISTCHANGED EVENT FROM FIRING
            // 3) I GUESS THE PROBLEM WITH USING JSONCONVERT.DESERIALIZEOBJECT<BOOK__ENTITY> IS THAT THE USE OF ADDRANGE IS OMITTED. ANY IDEAS HOW I CAN FIX THIS?
        }

        return record;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is a nice overload where you can "inject" everything you need `public static T? DeserializeObject<T>(string value, params JsonConverter[] converters)`